# Find Eigenvalues close to a Target for a Generalised Eigenvalue problem of the type Ax=λBx with A and B very sparse

Tags: linear-algebra, sparse-arrays, eigenvalues

So I have been using Mathematica as a tool to discretise large linear systems of PDEs and cast them as algebraic eigenvalue problems involving **very large sparse matrices**. These are usually **complex and non-hermitian**.

When the system is small enough, I can use `EigenSystem[{A,B}]` to get the whole spectrum. But when the system becomes very big I would usually export the resulting matrices and use some other dedicated solver like `SLEPc`and `MUMPS`.

I was wondering if there would be a way to skip this step and do everything within Mathematica. The systems I am dealing with are very big and so it is impractical to solve for the whole spectrum. So, one important feature I am after, is the possibility to specify a target eigenvalue around which the spectrum is computed.

In practice, this can be achieved by using the **Arnoldi** iterative methods. 
With SLEPc, I usually use the **Shift-and-invert method**.

Just to give your a clearer idea, here is a list and `MatrixPlot` of the kind of matrices I usually deal with:

[image: list of matrices]

[image: matrixplots]

Below is a reproduction of all the information I could find on the subject in the documentation. I found no further link or tutorial.

[image: part of the documentation for function EigenSystem]

It looks like the features I am after are either not fully released or well hidden. I would love to read any comment, suggestion you might have on that issue.

Comment: Look in the "Options" section of that page, under "Method": further suboptions are shown for each of the methods vailable. Perhaps that might help you.

Comment: I don't think *Mathematica*'s implementation of Arnoldi is yet capable of handling pencils, more so that the matrices are "complex and non-hermitian".

Comment: Something like `Eigensystem[m, 1, Method->{"Arnoldi", "Shift" -> μ}]`?

Comment: @CarlWoll I just saw that possibility following MarcoB's comment (thx). This is only a shift right ? There is no "invert".